# Slider control in sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part

i need to create a slider control which will be a connectable webpart .
How i go ahead and implement this in SHarepoint 2007.
Please provide any links . .

Answer (score 2):

First, become accustomed to writing basic connectable webparts in SharePoint, using this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765(v=office.12).aspx

Next, you'll need to think about how to pass the value of a slider through to the connection.

If you're stuck on this, you need to closely evaluate what you want your slider to do, and what values it passes through/updates.